# Trying to Submit and Email a contact form using jquery-validation. Passes validation, but no mail is received

Tags: php, jquery, validation, email

I am attempting to learn how to create a form, validate the input, sanitize that data, and email it to myself. I began by creating the HTML form and integrating the [jquery-validation plugin from here.](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation)

The client-side validation seems to be working great, not allowing the user to "submit" unless my rules are specified. However, I am having a hard time understanding actually *how to process and mail* this form to myself. From what I can tell, the ajax is successfully passing data to my PHP processing page, but I never receive any data in my email.

**HTML Form :**

```
<form id="contact-form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name *" name="firstName" id="firstName">
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name *" name="lastName" id="lastName">
<input type="text" placeholder="Street Address *" name="address" id="address" >
<select name="state" id="state" >
    <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">State *</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip *" name="zip" id="zip" >
<input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number *" name="phone" id="phone">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email Address (optional)" name="email" id="email">                         
<textarea rows="3" placeholder="Additional Message (optional)" name="message" id="message"></textarea>    
<input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Send Message">
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/validation.js"></script>
```

**Validation.js :**

```
$(function() {

$("#contact-form").validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: {
            required: true
        },
        lastName: {
            required: true
        },
        address: {
            required: true
        },
        state: {
            stateUS: true,
            required: true
        },
        zip: {
            zipcodeUS: true,
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            phoneUS: true,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            email: true
        },
        method: {
            lettersonly: true,
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/test/mail.php",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function() {alert('works');},
            error: function() {alert('failed');}
        });
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

**mail.PHP :**

```
<?php

    $firstName = $lastName = $address = $state = $zip = $phone = $email = $method = $message = "";
    $email_subject = $email_message = $headers = "";
    $email_to = "matt@gmail.com";

    $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);

    $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);

    $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);

    $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);

    $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);

    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);                                                               

    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);

    $email_subject = "New Meeting Request - ".$name;        
    $email_message = "Details below:\n\n";                                                      
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".$firstName."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".$lastName."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Address: ".$address."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".$state."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Zip Code: ".$zip."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone Number: ".$phone."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Email Address: ".$email."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Additional Message: ".$message."\n\n";

    $headers = 'From: PHP Form'."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: N/A'."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

    return true;

    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);                 //trims whitespace on both ends
       $data = stripslashes($data);         //removes extra slashes
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);     //converts special characters to HTML equivalents
       return $data;                        //returns cleaned data
    }

?>
```

Comment: To see what goes wrong don't suppress mail error. Let the script return the error message, if any, and, pass it to the ajax callback: `success: function(data) {alert(data);}`

Comment: Ah, thank you. Didn't realize I was suppressing with the @ command.

I have gone ahead and removed @mail() and changed it to mail(). I still receive a success message. No errors are shown.

Comment: See suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The mail() function only returns boolean as result. You should temporary change the error reporting level to get any message, and set it back after using mail.

**mail.php**

```
...
$errLevel = error_reporting(E_ALL);  // display all error messages

if(!mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
    echo 'Error sending email';
else echo 'All is fine';

error_reporting($errLevel);  // restore old error levels

//return true;  //this is not needed
```

**Validation.js**

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/test/mail.php",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(data) {alert(data);},
            error: function() {alert('failed');}
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit, I was able to verify that the mail() function is returning the correct result.

The problem is occurring due to issues with my hosting provider and my client's email settings.

Apparently you cannot send mail() using PHP if the email server is hosted elsewhere (in my case, privateemail.com). Makes sense, but I had not considered that my code was actually correct.

In order to get this working I needed to use the SMTP -> mail function instead of PHP's mail() function. I did this by utilizing the PHPMailer Plugin found here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer